# How to return an object property that matches conditions in a List<ObjectA> of List<ObjectB> (nested list) in java?

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-lists

I am trying to return an object property (or the object) efficiently in a List of lists.
Lets call my initial object `MasterObject`.
MasterObject has `List<ObjectA>` where ObjectA has `List<ObjectB>` that has property `ObjectC`.

`ObjectC` has multiple properties that I want to match (e.g. String type, int length) and I want to return property String `propertyID` of `ObjectC` or return the `ObjectC` itself (if a matching object exists).

I was able to determine whether such element exists using streams *anymatch*.

```
MasterObject.getListObjectA.stream()
    .anymatch(x -> x !=null && x.getListOjectB.stream().anymatch(y -> y.getObjectC().getType().equals("rf") && y.getObjectC().getLength() == 3));
```

Now I want to get a reference to the `ObjectC` or `ObjectB` so I can return `ObjectB.getObjectC.ID`.

Can this be achieved with streams?

Tips and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: “I want to return property String propertyID of ObjectC or return the ObjectC itself…” “Now I want to get a reference to the ObjectC or ObjectB so I can return ObjectB.getObjectC.ID.”  These are three separate tasks.  What do you actually need?  Do you want propertyIDs, ObjectC references, or ObjectB references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten the nested stream along with `filter` to filter an `ObjectC` instance matching the condition. We can use `findFirst` to find a (any) matching `ObjectC`.

```
 Optional<String> optionalPropertyId = objectAs.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(objectA -> objectA.getListObjectB().stream())
            .filter(objectB -> objectB.getObjectC().getType().equals("rf")
                    && objectB.getObjectC().getLength() == 3)
            .map(objectB -> objectB.getObjectC().getPropertyID())
            .findFirst();
```

The `flatMap` returns `Stream<ObjectB>` and the `filter` on this is same as your existing condition/check. If the check passes, it uses `map` to extract the `propertyID` of the `ObjectC`.

Note that the result is an `Optional` and could be empty if no `ObjectC` instances exist which match the passed predicate.

Comment: Thank you this solution worked. Do I not needed to filter(Objects::nonNull) or filter(objectB -> objectB != null && ... after the .flatMap?

Comment: In your code, you have `x -> x != null`. So here the equivalent would be to check if the objectA is null or not

Answer (score 0):

You can `flatMap` your lists.

```
List<ObjectB> results = master.getListObjectA().stream().flatMap(objA -> objA.getListObjectB().stream())
                .filter(objB -> objB.id.equals("xyz"))
                .toList();
```